# Ruby Error from Mysql Gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, irb

Ok I am embarrassed to come with such question, and unfortunately it a bit vague( to me) but I am just getting started coding with Ruby, and I came across error that i wasn't even able to Google.

I used `irb` to write this, even if I proceed further with queries, the fetched fields, rows etc. give me similar response to the one bellow.

```
require "mysql"
db = Mysql.new "localhost","user","password","database"
```

Output

```
=> #<Mysql:0x963abb0>
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, the port to MySQL is open, please let me know what other information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In `irb`, you can do `db.methods` to list the available methods for the `db` object. To perform a query, you can do something like the following

```
# list available tables
db.query('show tables').each do |row|
  puts row
end
```

Here's the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/2.9.1/frames)